# Three phase brushless DC motor driver using Three current sensor

Tags: avr, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I wrote a program for a brushless DC motor using three Hall effect sensors.
Now I want to
rewrite the same program for another brushless motor without Hall sensors.
Using three current sensor, I want to synchronize 3 phase of motor with the Mega2560 Micro-controller.

I have two interrelated questions:

- At the staring the motor, there is no current flowing how should I start the motor and then read current sensors?
- Hall sensors digitally return 3 phase of motor, how I can convert analog output of current sensor to 3 phase of motor similar to Hall?

Comment: Some type of open loop startup with current limiting. You just move from one phase to the next, accelerating, but limiting the current with a PID control loop. Maybe search for "open loop startup."

Comment: You can not do what you think. Hall sensors will tell you where the rotor is, current sensor will not: they tell you the current, but the current depends on what you do with the bridges. Maybe you can implement a "sensorless BLDC" (search info).

Comment: Even sensorless will require some extra hardware that taps into the motor phase wires.

Comment: Oh, yeah. If you want to control the motor sensorlessly, you still at least need voltage sensors on the individual phase voltages on top of the current sensors. I don't think it is possible to control the motor with current sensors only (other than open-loop  V/F control).